# Using overriden function in base class constructor for derived class

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, constructor, virtual

I'm very new to C++ programming so I wanted to write some simple code to get used to the syntax. I have deliberately ignored pointers and references for the moment.

During coding, I was practising inheritance and I wanted to create a class Hand which represents a hand of cards. The base class has a function called update(), which is used to initialize the "total" and "notation" properties upon construction. Moreover it is possible to add cards to the hand using the add() function which adds a card to the hand and triggers update() to update the properties appropriately.

```cpp
#include<vector>

class Hand
{
public:
    std::vector<int> cards;
    int total;
    std::string notation; // Abbreviated notation of the object
    // Constructor
    Hand(std::vector<int> cards);
    void update();
    void add(int card);
}

Hand::Hand(std::vector<int> cards)
{
    this->cards = cards;
    update();
}

void Hand::update()
{
    total = 0;
    notation += "{ ";
    for (int card: cards)
    {
        total += card;
        notation += std::to_string(card) + " ";
    }
    notation += "}";
}

void Hand::add(int card)
{
    cards.push_back(card);
    update();
}
```

Next, I wanted to create a more specific class of Hand called StandHand, which does all the same things as Hand but it also has a variable that changes when the total reaches a particular value.

Initially I thought I could just write the subclass as shown below, but alas.

```cpp
class StandHand : public Hand
{
public:
    int stand;
    StandHand(std::vector<int> cards, int stand);
    void update();
}

StandHand::StandHand(std::vector<int> cards, int stand) : Hand(cards)
{
    this->stand = stand;
    updateHand();
}

void StandHand::update()
{
    Hand::update();
    notation += stand <= total ? " (stand)" : "";
}
```

But when I invoke the add() method on a StandHand object, it does not use the StandHand::update() method, rather it uses the base update() method. How can I make sure that the add() method, when used in a subclass of Hand, uses the update() function of that subclass?

Comment: Your C++ book should have a chapter on virtual inheritance. This is where you will find additional information on how to do this.

Comment: You need to learn about `virtual` functions: `virtual void update()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters in the code there is no overloaded functions. The declaration of `update` in the derived class hides the declaration of the function with the same name in the base class.

As the member function `add` is declared in the base class then the name of the function `update` also is searched in the base class.

Declare the function `update` as a virtual function.

```
class Hand
{
public:
    // ...
    virtual void update();
};

class StandHand : public Hand
{
public:
    // ///
    void update() override;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code, first `void update();` in the base class needs to be declared `virtual`, so that compiler will know that derived classes might override it and use it.

```
virtual void update();
// add "=0;" if there is no base version of update()
```

And in the derived class write

```
void update() override;
//override is unnecessary but recommended
//it verifies that you do indeed overload a method from a base class
```

Second problem, **you cannot call methods from derived class in constructor of its base class**. What happens is that calling virtual base method results in calling the base version instead of the derived version. Think of it: the derived object isn't constructed yet but you already call one of its methods? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Isn't my base class also calling upon a function while it's being constructed? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JansthcirlU constructors are called in order "base to derived". Only in the constructor of the derived class the virtual methods get overridden; prior to that, base constructor has no idea who overrides it or if anything does. You might want to check out how virtual function call is implemented to get a better idea of what happens behind the lines.

Comment: even a call to a virtual function of _this_ class from constructor results in calling one of base class.